# How to mark pavement and grass without harming environment

Tags: pollution, alternatives

I'm looking for some kind of paint to make markings on the pavement and on a grassy area, so that the markings are well visible for a day or so.

Spray paint would do the trick but is not very environmentally friendly. Maybe grinding bright coloured chalk and dispensing it from a salt shaker would work?

Comment: For foot races I often see flour used. You can cut a corner of the bag and shake to apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For pavement, how about chalk?

For grass, here are a couple of products based on crushed limestone: no affiliation, just the result of a google search. These only seem to come in white though.

https://www.acehardware.com/departments/paint-and-supplies/specialty-paints/marking-and-striping/8337933

https://www.acehardware.com/departments/paint-and-supplies/specialty-paints/marking-and-striping/8192973

Comment: Hi, i looked into it and chalk and limestone are pretty much the same thing. Then i had trouble finding the crushed limestone marking-stuff in the Netherlands where i live. The reason is, it turns out spray-on markings are used more often here (http://www.sportbelijning.nl/natuurgras%20advies.html). So i'll go with the original plan and grind chalk.